# How to retrieve string with different language from Edittext

Tags: android, utf-8, android-edittext

I faced this problem 
 how can I retrieve string with another language (not English) from edittext?

Comment: i think you need [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) for better answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply call `toString()` in your TextWatcher:

Set your listener:
`name.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(name));`

Define your listener:

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
    private View view;
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String text = editable.toString();
    }
}
```

The language the String is in shouldn't matter until you try to store or display it.